# Outlook calendar peek (side view) does not include events from all accounts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, microsoft-outlook-365

I'm using Outlook (MS Office 365 for Small Business) on Windows 10 Professional. I have set to show calendar peek (in right side view). This works as expected, but only for my primary mail account.

Calendar peek does not include events from my second account. On the other hand, if I go to "full" calendar view I can see events from all my accounts.

How can I set calendar peek to show events from all mail accounts?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to display events for all accounts at once in Outlook.You can vote in this feedback:
https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/f5c8a184-78df-ed11-a81c-000d3a0fab07

Comment: Thank you, but the link you provided relates to "hover" functionality, not side view calendar.

Comment: You can also submit the features you want on the URL yourself.

Comment: Take a look at this photo: https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/71832a2a-f1f7-4a19-8294-9763c3760340.png. On the right side is the side-view calendar. In my case it only shows my primary account events. Why not all accounts?

Comment: Showing calendar events for all accounts is not supported at this time. Mine is the same as yours. By design.
https://www.bing.com/images/blob?bcid=ROtVTSY0c84GoPT-IwzU0mSuZ3sS.....5s